# Proxy not working after setting from an automatic script

Tags: windows-10, powershell, proxy, script

I set a proxy using a power shell script and it is showing fine in internet options however when I am opening the browser the proxy is not set.
I even checked the registry to see the current proxy values and they are showing the correct configuration but still not implemented in the browser.
I am using firefox and I tried setting manual proxy in Firefox settings, still doesnt work.
Thanks for any help

Comment: You say this... [I am using firefox and I tried setting manual proxy in Firefox settings, still, doesnt work.]...then this is not a PowerShell code issue, it is an environment one and you need to determine what that is.If you can't set it via the settings GUI, then there are other problems. [You are saying you are doing stuff like this][https://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Firefox#:~:text=How%20to%20Enter%20Proxy%20Settings%20in%20Firefox.%201,%22Network%20Proxy%22%20section%20and%20click%20Settings...%20More%20items] and it is not sticking? If so, that is a FF specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right. There was an extension "Windscribe" which has a kill switch and was not allowing my traffic to pass through unless connected to VPN.

Comment: Understood, glad to know that info guided you to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

A firefox extension named Windscribe has a kill switch and was not allowing traffic to pass through unless connected to the VPN.